# Action of braid groups on regular trees

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, trees, braid-groups

Question:

Are there any well known actions of braid groups on trees? For example is there some action of a braid group $ B_n $ on a $ p $ regular tree for some $ p $ such that the action is transitive on vertices and also transitive on directed edges?

Context:

We often understand a group by its actions. For a finite group or compact group, the theory of its unitary representations is very well behaved. Even for a general reductive algebraic group its representation theory is well behaved.

For finite groups we can also learn things by thinking of the finite group acting as automorphisms of a graph.

I'm not used to working with infinite groups that aren't algebraic groups over some field. Braid groups are an example of infinite groups that aren't algebraic groups over any field. Although there is a theory of unitary representations of Braid groups (e.g. certain values of the Burau representation and Lawrence–Krammer representation) the image of the Braid group is not a closed subgroup of the unitary group and so it is a bit beyond my intuition.

Since the Braid group is an infinite "discrete" group in my intuition it might be related to the automorphisms of an infinite tree.